# How to bypass CORS policy when sending get/post request from React JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, http-proxy-middleware

From my React JS app , I need to fetch data from servers in other domains.
However, I am prevented by CORS policy and not able to fetch the data.

Let us assume that my React app is running on localhost:3000 during the development.
I want to make get/post call to another server running on  http://myserver.com
The URL through which I want to fetch the data is http://ext-server.com/data/records?name=xyz

I have installed http-proxy-middleware thru npm and using it in my react app.
Created a setupProxy.js file under src folder with below content :

```
const { createProxyMiddleware} = require("http-proxy-middleware")
module.exports = app => {
   app.use(
      createProxyMiddleware('/data/records' , {
        target:'http://ext-server.com',
        changeOrigin: true
     })
 )
}
```

On the landing page of my react app (firstpage.js) when http://localhost:3000 is hit , I have added below piece of code to the button event that makes the get call to the http://ext-server.com

```
getTheData() {
  
let url = "http://ext-server.com/data/records?name=" + encodeURIComponent(this.state.name); 

axios.get(url,
  { 
    headers: {
     "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTL-8",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
     Accept: "application/json",
      }, 
      baseURL: 'http://ext-server.com'
   }
 ).then((response) => {
     console.log(response["access_token"]);
  }).catch(error) => {
       console.log("Error: ", error)
  }).then(function () {
       console.log("always call it")
});

}
```

In the package.json , I have added :

```
"proxy": "http://ext-server.com",
"homepage":"http://localhost:3000",
```

But I am still getting below error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ext-server.com/data/records?name= ' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy.

Is there anything that I am missing here ? what is the correct way to use this http-proxy-middleware?
Any help will be very useful!
Thanks

Comment: `getTheData() {
  
let url = "http://ext-server.com/data/records?name=" + encodeURIComponent(this.state.name); 

axios.get(url,
  { 
    headers: {
     "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTL-8",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
     Accept: "application/json",
      }, 
      baseURL: 'http://ext-server.com'
   }
 ).then((response) => {
     console.log(response["access_token"]);
  }).catch(error) => {
       console.log("Error: ", error)
  }).then(function () {
       console.log("always call it")
});

}` is this in the back end?

Comment: You cannot circumvent CORS from the client side (at least not in a browser), that is the whole point of CORS. Creating a proxy obviously works but you will run into all sorts of problems, e.g. regarding authentication, cookies, ... Does `ext-server.com` respond with proper CORS headers?

Comment: @Sohan Arafat no it's in front end

Comment: When you do app.use('/api', myProxyMiddlewareConfig) with a properly configured proxyMiddleware, I don't expect to see any client code pointing to ext-server.com, rather it should point to /api.

Comment: @James can you please elaborate the change that you are suggesting here?

Comment: @luk2302 Most probably ext-server.com does not respond with CORS headers. Tomorrow I might request some other ext2-server.com and not sure whether they will have CORS in their response or not. Hence using proxy

Answer (score 0):

The CORS policy is one and only administered by the web server and its settings. To allow CORS requests it has to be implemented on server side. No chance to do it from your client application.

Basically its just a header setting (below example for NodeJS):

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Sending that header will allow requests from every domain.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` header is a response type header, this means that it should go to in your server response. Also I advise you to not use the `*` symbol, instead I would rather match it with the origin header in your Request.